# Mac Textedit link to folder

Tags: macos, textedit

Is there a way to create a link to a folder in a Textedit document?

Textedit native interface clearly cannot link to a folder. Finder, drag folder or alias to textedit document, then directly or through system prompts an image icon is created in the Textedit document to represent the folder (or file), but no link is created.

Comment: The related question https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2731 has some relevant answers, for example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/2739 with AppleScript, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249269 with Automator, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362281 with a third-party tool

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a way to open another TextEdit file using a hotlink. The previous ideas are definitely a step forward for me. While this is a slightly different question, my results may be useful here.

Using the `file://` prefix on a full *file* path of the form:

```
file:///Users/myname/Documents/Personal/.../file.rtf
```

If the file is not already open, then the hotlink opens Finder and the file is highlighted.

If the file is already open, then the link takes me to the open file.

I have not found a way to get it to open a file that is not already open.

Results are a little differet when the link is to a *folder* instead of a file. Using the `file://` prefix on a full folder path of the form:

```
file:///Users/myname/Documents/Personal/.../foldername/
```

Whether or not the named folder is already open, the hotlink opens Finder for the *parent* folder and the named folder is highlighted.

If the parent folder is already open, then the link goes to that open folder and highlights the named folder.

I have not found a way to get it to open the target folder, other than by naming a file that is in that folder. The special name "`.`" does not work for that.

In Mojave 10.14.6, using hotlinks to other RTF files that open in TextEdit by default.

Comment: Directly opening files & folders from a TextEdit link can be done with an Automator service; see: https://github.com/nathan-artist/AppleScripts#applescript-service-to-open-local-url-from-hyperlink-in-textedit-instead-of-default-reveal-in-finder

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very time-consuming, but effective method to link to a folder from a Textedit document.

- Add a file to folder (e.g., an image file), select the file;
- Context menu 'Open with...' and select browser (Safari);
- Edit browser address bar path to delete filename, leaving path to folder, and copy this address to clipboard;
- In Textedit document, enter some text to link to folder (e.g., folder name);
- Select text, press Command-K and paste folder path, save.

Now you have a Textedit link to the folder that will open in Finder! Maybe... using Automator and System Preferences Keyboard, this could be turned into a context menu command. Though I am noticing that in macOS Sierra 10.12.1 the use of customizations for context commands is flakey, TO PUT IT MILDLY... **There has to be an easier way!**

macOS Sierra version 10.12.1

Comment: In Catalina, when I right-click on a file, neither Chrome nor Safari show up in the Open With... list, nor does Firefox or Opera. However, Brave Browser does, and a copy of an old versino of Chrome does,  which is in my Applications folder, named Google Chrome 90-0-4430-93.app (because that is the last version of Chrome that supports Cut-n-Paste in Tabs Outliner). I'm attempting to open a Markdown file, so that may have someting to do with it. In any case, a "non-standard" browser may allow you to get the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Chrome nor Safari to allow me to select a file path. This is an updated version of Mark Stewart's response that worked for me.

- Right click and select "get info" on the file you want to link to in the text document. (You can also select the file and hit "Command + i" to bring up the info dialog box)
- Right click the file path in the "Where" field under the "General Section" and select copy
- Go to the TextEdit document that you want to create the link in
- Select the text you want to use as a link
- Select text, press Command-K and paste folder path, but don't hit save yet.
- Add the text "file:" without the quotes to the beginning of the link
- Add a "/" character (not including the quotes) and the filename and the extension to the end of the link.
- Now hit ok or save

I am sure someone could create a hot folder or right click menu that would build the path and precede it with file: and save it to the clipboard automatically.

macOS Catalina 10.15

Answer (score 0):

The `Open` service should work for opening files and folders from paths in *TextEdit* and other text editors.

Two ways of **getting a file or folder path into *TextEdit***:

1. **For plain text documents:** Simply drag'n'drop a file from *Finder* to your *TextEdit* document or
2. **For RTF formatted documents:** Select the file or folder in *Finder*, copy the file path (`Command + Option + C`), select your document in *TextEdit*, paste the path to the document (`Command + V`). That avoids the icon and pastes a text link to formatted and unformatted *TextEdit* documents.

The result will be something like this: `/Path/To/File.ext` for files or `/Path/To/Folder` for folders

To **open a file or folder path from *TextEdit* with the `Open` service**

1. Select the whole path in *TextEdit* (e.g. by `left-click + hold + move` or by moving the cursor with the help of the `Arrow` keys to the beginning or the end of the path, then select the path by pressing `Shift + Arrow left/right` keys, optionally in combination with `Command` or `Option` key)
2. Select the service `Open` from the *Service Menu* (*Contextual* or *TextEdit* menu).
3. Confirm the dialog `Confirm Service`: `TextEdit wants to use the restricted Service “Open.”` by pressing `Run Service`

You might also want to **setup a keyboard shortcut** for utilizing the Service `Open` (e.g. `Command + Shift + O`). It can be done in * > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Text > Open*. In the same Keyboard setting window tab, you can also activate `All controls` for dialog boxes, so that you can confirm `Run Service` by pressing `Spacebar` to get keyboard control for the whole task.

Answer (score 0):

**Automator**:
workflow receives current 'files or folders' in 'Finder'.
*Utilities*:
'Copy to Clipboard'. Then
save service as:
'Copy Path'.

**Finder**: right click object (folder or file) and select service *Copy Path*.

**TextEdit**: edit link, type *file:* and paste path from clipboard.